# Spring Expression Lanuage SPEL: concate two properties and assign value to third property

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, spring-el

I am new to SPEL in Spring. I am not sure whether we can do something like this?

```
<bean id="student1" class="Student">
   <property name="firstName" value="John"/>
   <property name="lastName" value="Smith"/>
   <property name="fullName" value="#{firstName + lastName}" />
</bean>
```

I want to use SPEL in XML for my fullName property that is concatenation of firstName and lastName property.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't do it in the `Student.getFullName()` for better encapsulation and consistency? Otherwise someone can set for `firstName` and `lastName` one values, but for `fullName` - the different. And you will be surprised in the end!

From other side SpEL doesn't support that case. It can be used to populate values from some external beans with simple single-line logic. However you try to get values from the same bean. And I'm sure you end up with an exception, because there  no `firstName` and `lastName` beans in the context.